# Python Unexpected keyword argument' in constructor call

Tags: python, class, constructor, arguments, keyword

Hi and thanks in advance for your help.  I am not a Python expert but an accomplished programmer in other languages.

I'm getting the error on "is_server_running"

Client

```
from ibw.client import IBClient

REGULAR_USERNAME = 'MY_ACCOUNT_USERNAME'
REGULAR_ACCOUNT = 'MY_ACCOUNT_NUMBER'

# Create a new session of the IB Web API.
ib_client = IBClient(username=REGULAR_USERNAME,
                     account=REGULAR_ACCOUNT,
                     client_gateway_path=None,
                     is_server_running=True)
```

```
class IBClient():

    def __init__(self, username: str, account: str, client_gateway_path: str = None, is_server_running: 
                 bool = True) -> None

        self.account = account
        self.username = username
        self.client_gateway_path = client_gateway_path
        self.client_portal_client = ClientPortal()

        self.api_version = 'v1/'
        self._operating_system = sys.platform
        self.session_state_path: pathlib.Path = 
                                 pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.joinpath('server_session.json').resolve()
        self.authenticated = False
        self._is_server_running = is_server_running

        # Define URL Components
        ib_gateway_host = r"https://localhost"
        ib_gateway_port = r"5000"
        self.ib_gateway_path = ib_gateway_host + ":" + ib_gateway_port
        self.backup_gateway_path = r"https://cdcdyn.interactivebrokers.com/portal.proxy"
        self.login_gateway_path = self.ib_gateway_path + "/sso/Login?forwardTo=22&RL=1&ip2loc=on"

[more code]

Again thanks in advance for your help

Bob
```

Comment: Did you pip install this package? It might be that the example code you have is now out of date, looking at github it was updated on the 5th Sept. It no longer appears to have 'is_server_running' https://github.com/chrjxj/ibclient/blob/c1a4c82e1f0d7f65eb649869ecd1082d50117eb7/ibclient/ib_client.py

Comment: I cloned it yesterday.  If I look at client.py on github it still has class IBClient()
    def __init__(self, username: str, account: str, client_gateway_path: str = None, is_server_running: bool = True) -> None: